# Arbitrary arguments in Elixir Macros - wrapping a body

Tags: macros, elixir

I'm working on a small library dealing with ETS and I want to be able to exit functions early if the table doesn't exist. I can't put this in a guard because Elixir prevents talking to `:ets` in a guard, and so I have to basically put this check in every function, which ends up looking something horrible like this (code is to demo - I know it's messy :)):

```
def get_and_update(cache, key, modifier) do
  unless is_ets_table(cache) do
    { :error, create_error(cache) }
  else
    set(cache, key, modifier.(get(cache, key)))
  end
end
```

Is there a way to macro this into something as follows?

```
deftable get_and_update(cache, key, modifier) do
  set(cache, key, modifier.(get(cache, key)))
end
```

The check for the missing table would be implicit in the `deftable` Macro.

I've read up on Macros but I can't seem to make out what exactly is going on, so if you could explain your answer I'd appreciate it.

Aside from the mess, I also want to make it easier on the developer to just use the macro name rather than having to always remember to check for the table.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I should also note that the number of arguments can easily (and will) change.

Comment: What do your `set` and `get` functions look like? Seems like one or both of them could be written to return the error and then you don't need a macro.

Comment: @CoderDennis they could very easily be rewritten - the problem is there are N functions besides `set` & `get` - I don't want to have to write it N times repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this as following, but please let me know if there's something better:

```
defmacro deftable({ func_name, _func_ctx, [cache|_] = args }, do: body) do
  quote do
    def unquote(func_name)(unquote_splicing(args)) do
      if not is_ets_table(unquote(cache)) do
        unquote(body)
      else
        { :error, no_table(unquote(cache)) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think using `unless` with `else` is a bit harder to understand than just using ´if´ and flipping the branches around. Other than that I think this looks fine.

Comment: @PatrickOscity ok cool, thanks :) normally I'd agree about the `if`, however I personally prefer to get the error cases out of the way first, so you can immediately see any short-circuits.